# SAS print ASCII value of special character

Tags: sas, ascii

I am using the notalnum function in SAS. The input is a db field. Now, the function is returning a value that tells me there is a special character at the end of every string.
It is not a space character, because I have used COMPRESS function on the input field.

How can I print the ACII value of the special character at the end of each string?

Answer (score 3):

The $HEX. format is the easiest way to see what they are:

```
data have;
  var="Something With A Special Char"||'0D'x;
run;

data _null_;
  set have;
  rul=repeat('1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 ',3);  *so we can easily see what char is what;
  put rul=;
  put var= $HEX.;
run;
```

You can also use the `c` option on compress (`var=compress(var,,'c');`) to compress out control characters (which are often the ones you're going to run into in these situations).

Finally - 'A0'x is a good one to add to the list, the non-breaking space, if your data comes from the web.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the position of the character within the ascii table you can use the `rank()` function, e.g.:

```
data _null_;
  string = 'abc123';
  do i = 1 to length(string);
    asc = rank(substr(string,i,1));
    put i= asc=;
  end;
run;
```

Gives:

```
i=1 asc=97
i=2 asc=98
i=3 asc=99
i=4 asc=49
i=5 asc=50
i=6 asc=51
```

Joe's solution is very elegant, but seeing as my hex->decimal conversion skills are pretty poor I tend to do it this way.

Comment: But the HEX value is actually easier to use than the decimal equivalent since you can use it in a literal.  '0D'x is a carriage return.

Comment: Hex would also better when working with unicode data too I suppose.